# Apache Location and Directory access

Tags: apache-2.2, directory

I have Apache 2.2 running on CentOS 6.4 
There is application in / directory and folder where are some files, lets say it is /public.
I need to allow access to / directory to ip1, ip2, ip3 and allow access to /public folder to ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5. And ip5 and ip4 are not allowed to access to /.
I tried to do it with this config:

```
<Location / >
    Require ip ip1 ip2 ip3
</Location>
Alias /public /some/path
<Directory /some/path>
    Options +Indexes
    Require ip ip1 ip2 ip3 ip4 ip5
</Directory>
```

But ip4 and ip5 cannot access /public folder.
How can I grant access to this IP adresses?

**UPD1**
If I use

```
<Location /some/path>
Require ip ip1 ...
</Location>
```

instead of using Alias and Directory, then I have access, but there is no list of files in browser. Seems, that I should use  instead, but then I have no access to this directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define /public as an **Alias URL** not a **Directory**. So, configuration doesn't work because Apache doesn't find /public as Directory.

Try change

```
<Directory /public>
    Options +Indexes
    Require ip ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Location /public>
    Require ip ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5
</Location>
```

Note: Option directive doesn't work inside Location directive

As Alternative configuration, you can specify /some/path instead /public in Directory directive

```
<Directory /some/path>
    Options +Indexes
    Require ip ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4, ip5
</Directory>
```

**UPDATE**

You should place IP restriction in `Location` directive, because the `Location` will merge after `Directory` (see [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging)). Updated configuration is

```
Alias /public /some/path
<Location /public>
    Require ip ip1 ip2 ip3 ip4 ip5
</Location>
<Directory /some/path>
   Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: if I change Directory to Location, then I still cannot access /public folder.

Comment: Try alternative answer, change `/public` to a directory

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have edited my configuration. There was directory with /some/path, not with /public.

Comment: May it be, that <Location / > block access to /public?

Comment: You are right. Please see my updated answer.